# Having trouble understanding traits and generics in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm incredibly new to trying to write generics, and Rust's traits continue to elude my understanding. I've got this piece of code:

```
pub trait Mapper {
    fn prg_rom_read(&self, addr: u16) -> u8 {}
    fn prg_rom_write(&mut self, addr: u16, val: u8) {}
    fn chr_rom_read(&self, addr: u16) -> u8 {}
    fn chr_rom_write(&mut self, addr: u16, val: u8) {}
}

pub fn choose_mapper<M: Mapper>(rom_header: &RomHeader) -> M {
    match rom_header.mapper_number {
        0 => Mapper1::new(rom_header),
        _ => panic!("Unsupported mapper: {:#}", rom_header.mapper_number),
    }
}

struct Mapper1 {
    prg_ram: Box<[u8]>,
    prg_rom: Box<[u8]>,
    chr: Box<[u8]>,
}

impl Mapper1 {
    pub fn new(rom_header: &RomHeader) -> Self {
        Mapper1 {
            prg_ram: {
                let size = rom_header.prg_ram_size as usize * 8192;
                vec![0; size].into_boxed_slice()
            },
            prg_rom: {
                let size = rom_header.prg_rom_size as usize * 16384;
                vec![0; size].into_boxed_slice()
            },
            chr: {
                let size = rom_header.chr_rom_size as usize * 8192;
                vec![0; size].into_boxed_slice()
            },
        }
    }
}

impl Mapper for Mapper1 {
    fn prg_rom_read(&self, addr: u16) -> u8 {}

    fn prg_rom_write(&mut self, addr: u16, val: u8) {}

    fn chr_rom_read(&self, addr: u16) -> u8 {}

    fn chr_rom_write(&mut self, addr: u16, val: u8) {}
}
```

in which I try to define a trait, impl that trait on several structs, then have a function which returns one of those structs. Is this even possible?

I get the compiler error:

```
expected `_`,
    found `mapper::Mapper1`
(expected type parameter,
    found struct `mapper::Mapper1`) [E0308]
src/mapper.rs:11     match rom_header.mapper_number {
src/mapper.rs:12         0 => Mapper1::new(rom_header),
src/mapper.rs:13         _ => panic!("Unsupported mapper: {:#}", rom_header.mapper_number),
src/mapper.rs:14     }
src/mapper.rs:11:5: 14:6 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/mapper.rs:12:14: 12:38 note: match arm with an incompatible type
src/mapper.rs:12         0 => Mapper1::new(rom_header),
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pub fn choose_mapper<M: Mapper>(rom_header: &RomHeader) -> M` means that the function returns `M`, which is some (not any) `Mapper`. The generics are provided *by the caller* (either explicitly with `choose_mapper::<SomeM>(foo)` or most of the time inferred from context as in `let bar: SomeM = choose_mapper(foo)`).

Your function tries to return a `Mapper1` (which is some `M`, but not necessarily the same as the one the caller wants).

You should change the signatures to

```
pub fn choose_mapper(rom_header: &RomHeader) -> Box<Mapper>;
```

which allows the function to choose what it returns.

Interestingly there is [a very active RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1522) which would allow a function to choose what it returns (usually referred as `impl Trait`, although the syntax has not been chosen yet).

Comment: That makes sense. Should I then use Box::new() to in the match arms of choose mapper? or should each new() return a Box<Mapper>?

If I do this, then if I try to do this in another module:

Comment: So clearly, I have to use Box::new(), bute when I try to call choose_mapper from another module and assign the result to either a variable, or struct field, I get this error: 

unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required. 

I have tried casting and type specification to no avail...

Comment: Did you remove `<M: Mapper>`? If you return a box, the function is not generic anymore.

Comment: I ended up removing it, which worked! But I'm confused. If it's not generic, how is it able to return various types? Or is it just that it returns a pointer to a heap allocated data structure?

Comment: “Or is it just that it returns a pointer to a heap allocated data structure?” → Yes, that's the only way for a function to return any trait instance for now, hence the `impl Trait` RFC.